# Step in the proof that integral elements form a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $K$ be a field and $A$ an integral domain such that $A \subset K$. Let $\alpha \in K$ be integral over $A$. Then the $A$-submodule $M$ of $K$ generated by $\lbrace 1, \alpha, \dots, \alpha^{n-1}\rbrace$ has the property that $\alpha M \subset M$.

I want to check if my understanding of this is correct.

Since $\alpha$ is integral over $A$, there exist $a_i \in A$ such that $$\alpha^n + a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1} + \dots + a_1 \alpha + a_0 = 0$$

Let $M$ be the $A$-submodule of $K$ generated by $\lbrace 1, \alpha, \dots, \alpha^{n-1}\rbrace$. Then we write

$$M = A + A\alpha + A\alpha^2 + \dots + A\alpha^{n-1}.$$

Since $\alpha^n$ can be written as an $A$-linear combination of the elements of the set $\lbrace 1, \alpha, \dots, \alpha^{n-1}\rbrace$, we have that $\alpha^n \in M$, so that $$\alpha M = A\alpha + A\alpha^2 + \dots + A\alpha^{n-1} + A\alpha^n = A\alpha + A\alpha^2 + \dots + A\alpha^{n-1}\ \ \ \ (\star)$$

and so $\alpha M \subset M$.

In the step $(\star)$, does the fact that $\alpha^n \in M$ make the term $A\alpha^n$ redundant?

Comment: What do you denote $M$?

Comment: @Bernard $M$ is an $A$-submodule of $K$.

Comment: You wrote *the* $A$-submodule. Which one?

Comment: @Bernard I see what you mean, I'll edit my question. I mean the $A$-submodule $M$ of $K$ generated by the elements $\lbrace 1, \alpha, \dots, \alpha^{n-1}\rbrace$. Now it's obvious that this is finitely generated.. because I've chosen it that way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as a member of a system of generators, it makes it redundant. Actually it's easy to show by induction that
$$K[\alpha]=\bigl\langle 1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\dots, \alpha^i,\dots\bigr\rangle=\bigl\langle 1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\dots, \alpha^{n-1}\bigr\rangle,$$
and that they're a basis of the $K$-vector  space $K[\alpha]$, if the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree $n$.